# WordPress published date getting broken

Tags: php, wordpress

I could use some help.

I have a site that keeps having the RSS go down because of a super future-dated post. And it's not on purpose. So it is screwing up the last updated field in the RSS.

Now, it is pulling in these posts based off a plugin that was custom written for it.

What I THINK is happening is that when that plugin was developed, they used a date format that isn't the default for WordPress and so it is occasionally throwing a monkey wrench in the works and post dating to January 19th, 2038 (always the same date)

Here is the code for setting publish date:

```
        if($item->pubDate == ''){
            $item->pubDate = date('D, d M Y h:i:s').' +0000';
        }
        $news_date = date('Y-m-d D h:i:s', strtotime($item->pubDate));
        $news_title = htmlentities($item->title);
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    =>  $news_title,
          'post_type'     => 'news',
          'post_content'  => $item->description,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_date'     => $news_date
        );
```

As opposed to the WordPress default Y-m-d H:i:s

Anyone think this might be the problem?

It's intermittent- so very hard to test.

Comment: How do you know that the cause is "super future-dated post"? Can you share some error messages?

Comment: Because the "last updated" and published date are 2038. Pretty straight forward.